# Want to Change current url to previous page url ( second domain)?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url

We have two domains.

1. ***www.mysite1.com***
2. ***www.mysite2.com***

I have to send user from ***www.mysite1.com/category/cup.php*** to ***www.mysite2.com/details.php***. User have to enter some details and when he clicks the next button he will come back to exactly same page form where he was redirected ***www.mysite1.com/category/cup.php***

The only thing is, the URL is changing during this whole procedure.

I don't want to tell the user that he is right now in ***www.mysite2.com/details.php***

Is there any thing(javascript, php, .htaccess or jquery), that I can do to change the URL of the second site to first one from where I am redirecting the user.

PS:

I study many question related to such scenario, but didn't find this kind of situation. I know changing the entire url may lead to phishing attacks. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.  You can fake it with a frame.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iframe to show the content of the second site without leaving the first. By giving the iframe a name and adding a target attribute to a form, you can send data from your first to your second domain. If you need the frame to cover all of the page, you can style it using CSS.

```
<form action="http://www.mysite2.com/details.php" target="details">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<iframe name="details" />
```

Then, from the second domain, you can once again use the target attribute of a form to send data back to the first domain in the top window.

```
<form action="http://www.mysite1.com/category/cup.php" target="_top">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```